# Better command for $\require{cancel} \cancel{\exists}$ (There does not exist)

Tags: discussion, mathjax

After searching the MathsJax tutorial pages, I couldn't find an actual symbol for $\require{cancel} \cancel{\exists}$

The way I have written it <\require{cancel} \cancel{\exists}> is the best I could think of, but it seems ridiculous compared to the simple <\exists> command for $\exists$.

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: `\not\exists` $\not\exists$

Comment: Amazing, honestly I just couldn't find this!

Comment: From the Mathjax quick reference guide: `You can use \not to put a slash through almost anything`.

Comment: Maybe the quick reference needs to make this more prominent.

Comment: @TheSimpliFire - I don't know how you resisted answering "$\not \exists$ exists".

Comment: Better yet, $\lnot \exists$: `\lnot exist`.  If your question relates to logic, or the use of quantifiers, and their negation, then the standard notation is `\neg \exists`, $\neg \exists$ or `\lnot \exists`

Comment: Or `\nexists` $\nexists$

Comment: @CormJack: https://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html is a helpful tool: You *draw* what you need and get a list of suggestions.

Comment: Thank you very much for the helpful answers everyone, I might turn these into an answer!